# How can I count the number of files edited per day via git log?

Tags: git, git-log

`git log --name-only` seems to help, but how do I count these up by filename?

It returns something like:

```
commit bbd0cf6a25c742bf5e5734fa544c041052f5cf70
Merge: 0aec39a 20cabfb
Author: Adones Pitogo <pitogo.adones@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Oct 31 21:06:46 2014 +0800

    Merge pull request #10 from agibson-fl/master

    Use readAsArrayBuffer() instead of deprecated readAsBinaryString().

commit 20cabfbcc42f0978ce70cdb1912c8672c0abf313
Author: agibson-fl <agibson@frontlinetechnologies.com>
Date:   Thu Oct 30 11:57:37 2014 -0400

    Properly annotate function

dist/angular-base64-upload.js
dist/angular-base64-upload.min.js
src/angular-base64-upload.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `git whatchanged` along with the `cut` command in unix?